# Mongoose: Model.find() returns an empty array when filtering by boolean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema defined in my app (node.js w/ express):

```
const ArtistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    year: {type: Number, required: true},
    genres: {type: [String], required: true},
    imageUrl: {type: String, required: false},
    trending: {type: Boolean, required: false, default: false},
    trendingDate: {type: Date, required: false}
});
```

and a route that is supposed to retrieve those entries, who have `trending` set to `true`:

```
// GET trending
router.get('/trending', (req, res) => {
    artist.Artist.find({trending: true}).exec((err, trendingArtists) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
            return;
        }
        res.json(trendingArtists);
    });
});
```

However, it always returns an empty array when i try to filter by `trending` field, even though there are items in my collection that have `trending` set to `true`. I have tried wrapping everything in single and double quotes and using `1` instead of `true`, but no query returns results. Filtering by other fields works just fine, not filtering at all returns all entries as expected.

The entries in mongo shell look like this:

```
> db.artists.find({},{name:1,trending:1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de942074a486e2c21246fb9"),
    "name" : "Unwound",
    "trending" : "true"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de942074a486e2c21246fba"),
    "name" : "Ladytron",
    "trending" : "true"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de942074a486e2c21246fbb"),
    "name" : "Depeche Mode",
    "trending" : "true"
}
```

`console.log`ing the results in the app produces this:

```
[
  {
    genres: [ 'post-hardcore', 'noise rock', 'indie rock' ],
    trending: true,
    _id: 5de942074a486e2c21246fb9,
    name: 'Unwound',
    year: 1991,
    imageUrl: '2a7f00a1f8e0ab37c647600f6abff67e.jpg',
    trendingDate: 2019-12-20T18:48:53.000Z
  },
  {
    genres: [ 'synthpop', 'electroclash', 'dream pop' ],
    trending: true,
    _id: 5de942074a486e2c21246fba,
    name: 'Ladytron',
    year: 1999,
    imageUrl: 'f26cc1ae1fef371793622bd199b4bb52.jpg',
    trendingDate: 2019-12-20T18:49:05.000Z
  },
  {
    genres: [ 'synthpop', 'new wave' ],
    trending: true,
    _id: 5de942074a486e2c21246fbb,
    name: 'Depeche Mode',
    year: 1980,
    imageUrl: 'e5328919dac971af86dd034781a2da71.jpg',
    trendingDate: 2019-12-20T18:49:43.000Z
  }
]
```

I am at my wits' end. What could cause filtering by a boolean field to break the query regardless of what i specify as the value (i have tried `true`, `'true'`, `"true"`, `1`, `'1'`, as well as the falsy counterparts)?

**edit**: i tried a few things since:

1) filtering the results after the query was executed works fine (i.e just writing `res.json(trendingArtists.filter(a => a.trending === true));`), though it's obviously not the way i would like to deal with filtering my queries

2) the collection i'm querying was created and edited manually, and not via api that my app implements. If i insert a new entry using a POST request via api, that entry will be returned by the query, provided `trending` was set to `true`

3) editing existing entries with PATCH requests where i set `trending` to `false` and then back to `true` also works, though it messes up the `trendingDate` field that is set to current date each time `trending` is changed to `true`

4) if the query works for an entry, it works no matter what i put as the value for the filter, as long as it's truthy for mongoose. `.find({trending: true})` works just as well as `.find({trending: '1'})`

I guess the problem is mongoose not recognizing my manually inserted values as truthy at all, even though theoretically they should be cast to true. My problem is solved, I guess? I do not plan to insert values manually in the future, this was just for testing, and those that few that are inserted can be fixed fairly easily, but i don't think it should matter for mongoose whether i edit the entries manually or via `Model.save`. It seems like a bug - should i close the question and open a bug report on their github?

Comment: The mongoose syntax is Model.find() so in your case `Artist.find({trending: true}).exec((err, trendingArtists) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
            return;
        }
        res.json(trendingArtists);
    });`

Comment: where is the non-empty console.log array coming from?

Comment: @C.Gochev i import the entire file containing the schema, so artist.Artist.find() is equivalent to Artist.find() if i just imported the class. All the other queries in my app are written in the same fashion and they work just fine

Comment: @KatherineR the console.log comes from the same request if i remove the filtering (`.find({trending: true}) => .find({})`), just before i return the results (`console.log(trendingArtists)` before `res.json(trendingArtists)`. Making an http req via postman/browser also returns correct entries